# Textures in cycles are black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, texturing

[image]

I created a bridge, created the uvs and created a material with a texture in cycles. I can see the textured result when I set the viewport shading to material, but when I try to render the image, the material just appears to be black.

Any idea why this could happen?

[blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27780)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bridge is showing up as black because it has no shader on it. You need to add a shader to it to be able to render it. Let's use a diffuse shader.

1. In the node editor, <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> Shader -> Diffuse
2. Connect the output from the Hue node to the color input of the diffuse shader.
3. Connect the BSDF output from the diffuse shader to the Material Output's Surface input.

[image]

[image]